# List to string to lists of letter

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert a list of strings to a list of letters/numbers but keeping the length of list the same. Here is my list look like,

```
a = ["0587828028", "2967480535"]
```

My code to convert the above list to split the string and save in a new list.

```
new_a = []
for i in range(len(a)):
        new_a += a[i]
```

And the output is on list,

```
['0', '5', '8', '7', '8', '2', '8', '0', '2', '8', '2', '9', '6', '7', '4', '8', '0', '5', '3', '5']
```

Desired output should be 2 list:

```
['0', '5', '8', '7', '8', '2', '8', '0', '2', '8'] ['2', '9', '6', '7', '4', '8', '0', '5', '3', '5']
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated, I am very new in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the built-in [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) iterable expansion:

```
a = ["0587828028", "2967480535"]

new_a = [list(x) for x in a]
# [['0', '5', '8', '7', '8', '2', '8', '0', '2', '8'],
#  ['2', '9', '6', '7', '4', '8', '0', '5', '3', '5']]
```